# Grails: how to handle java bean validation on Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm using Java entity classes as domain objects in Grails application. These classes have JSR 303 validation annotations (@Size, @NotEmpty etc...)

Grails controllers and views work fine with these entity classes, but when I try "bean.validate()" its always true.

Comment: Refer [this](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/hibernate.html#mappingWithHibernateAnnotations) for how-to. Stress on "Adding Constraints" part.

Comment: I already did this, my point is, when I use @NotNull (for instance), when i create a bean with the specified property "Null", the "bean.validate()" return true. Is there a solution to make Grails take into consideration JSR 303 validation annotations ?

Comment: Illustrate in details what you have tried with examples, it will be easier to pin point issues.

Answer (score 0):

You might need [JPA plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20200225125625/http://grails.org/plugin/jpa) to deal with JSR 303 annotations. Also have a look at this [defect](https://web.archive.org/web/20120511224148/http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5920).